# create a new git repository after deleting an old one

Tags: git

I'm not sure what has happened to my git repository, but for two days, every time I make a commit it starts deleting files seemingly at random, and then not letting me merge because of conflicts etc. etc.

I've got the app back to a usable state now, and I thought I would just delete the .git file and run `git init` to create a new git.

When I do that, I get

```
 git init
fatal: cannot copy '/usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/commit-msg.sample' to '/media/sf_Ruby192/myapp/.git/hooks/commit-msg.sample': Operation not permitted
```

--------------- UPDATE of LS -al

This is running in virtual box ubuntu on Windows host. The strange thing is this has been running for about 7 months without issue, and then all of a sudden GIT started deleteing files and I figured my .git was corrupted tried to re-build it and ran into all these problems.

```
total 62
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 2012-03-16 15:03 .
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 8192 2012-03-15 13:29 ..
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 2012-02-20 06:43 app
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 2012-03-16 09:45 config
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  161 2011-12-27 05:31 config.ru
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 2012-03-08 09:58 db
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 2011-12-27 05:31 doc
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 1369 2012-02-27 07:23 Gemfile
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4374 2012-02-27 07:24 Gemfile.lock
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   86 2012-02-22 13:21 .gitignore
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 2012-02-20 06:43 lib
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 2012-02-22 08:50 log
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 2012-03-18 09:02 public
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  274 2011-12-27 05:31 Rakefile
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 9386 2011-12-27 05:31 README
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 2012-02-27 07:16 redis
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 2011-12-27 05:31 s
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 2011-12-27 05:31 script
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 2011-12-27 05:31 solr
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    4 2012-02-20 06:43 sunspot-solr.pid
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 2011-12-27 05:31 test
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 2011-12-27 05:31 thin
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 2011-10-09 09:23 tmp
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 2011-12-27 05:31 vendor
```

------------------UPDATE-----------------------------

going through the steps recommended by Brian, there is a `.git` directory (which I new, and had renamed before running the initial `git init`. when i do an `ls -l .git`, I get

```
ls cannot access .git: No such file or directory
```

However, i can cd into the .git folder, but also can't run `-ls` from inside .git as I get

```
ls cannot access directory: Operation not permitted
```

any suggestions on how to get out of this hole??

Comment: are you having any issues with your filesystem?  for example has your filesystem been remounted as read-only?  or maybe there is a permissions issue?

Comment: @kclair, git is telling me I'm having problems (or it is having problems) but I've been adding, deleting, moving files without issue.

Comment: ok... i'm just saying that i think the error looks like a straight filesystem or permissions error.  does /media/sf_Ruby192/myapp/.git/ already exist?  what does an ls -la of that directory look like?

Comment: Can you paste in the output of `ls -al` in the top level directory? Also, what file system are you running this on? It looks like it might be a flash drive or something, given that it's mounted under `/media`.

Comment: @BrianCampbell thanks for your help with this, I've updated the question annd I'm on Ubuntu in VirtualBox with a Windows host.

Comment: You said there is a `.git` directory, but I don't see it in the output of `ls`. Where is this `.git` directory you are talking about?

Comment: Also, I notice that all of these files and directories are owned by root. Are you running as root, or are you running as a user in the `vboxsf` group (you should be able to check using `groups` or `id`)? Finally, if there isn't a `.git` directory there, what happens if you try to make one manually, using `mkdir .git`?

Answer (score 1):

To debug a problem with permissions, it is generally useful to check the permissions of the files in question: the source file, the destination file, and the destination directory.

Try `ls -l /usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/commit-msg.sample` to determine the permissions on your commit-msg.sample template; if you don't have read permission, then you won't be able to read it (`git init` copies several template files into your git repository; if it can't read the source files, you will get an error).

Next, try checking out the permissions for the destination files. From your project directory, run `ls -al`. Check to see what the permissions are for `.` (the current directory). Do you have write permission for `.`? Is there already a `.git` directory? Do you have write permission for it? If there is already a `.git` directory, then do an `ls -l` in there. Is there already a `hooks` directory? Do you have write permission in it? Finally, see what happens if you manually try copying `/usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/commit-msg.sample` to your `.git/hooks` directory. Do you get the same error?

It may be that following these steps will help you solve the problem yourself. If not, please put the output of those `ls -l` commands in your question, which will help us figure out what is going on.

Comment: thanks Brian, I did what you said, and updated the question with the issues with the `.git` folder. it appears you are correct that something is screwy with the permissions there. unfortunately, I can't get `ls` to output the permissions for that folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem myself. It turned out that the shell was holding on to some properties about the git repo that was deleted. After deleting I was getting the same `fatal: cannot copy` error. Closing the shell and opening a new one solved the problem. In a new shell I was able to init a new git repo. I have also had this problem when attempting to re-cloning a repo after deleting it. Starting a new shell solved the problem again.

Comment: I had this problem on a Windows machine and in my case it wasn't enough to restart the shell (Git Bash). I kept getting the `fatal: cannot copy` error, but after rebooting Windows it worked without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem.
The reason was disk full...